# Discord bot in node: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here is my code I keep on getting an error on:

```css
const {
    Message
} = require('discord.js');

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('../client/Client');

module.exports = {
    name: 'apply',
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        message.channel.send('DM\'ing you, here is a reminder, you have to have DMs open for me to start and application process so remember to open DMs if they are closed.')
        const questions = [`Would You Like To Apply?`, `This is a test correct?`, `am I friends with you`, `is this bot cool?`];
        const f = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Hello would you answer some questions?`)
            .setDescription(`I have seen you have sent the command a!apply in ${message.guild.name}.`)
        const dmChannel = await message.author.send(f);
        const collector = dmChannel.channel.createMessageCollector((msg) => msg.author.id == message.author.id);
        let i = 0;
        const res = [];
        dmChannel.channel.send(questions[0])
        collector.on('collect', async (msg) => {
            if (questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
            const answer = msg.content;
            res.push({
                question: questions[i],
                answer
            });
            i++;
            if (questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
            else {
                dmChannel.channel.send(questions[i]);
            }
        });
        collector.on('end', async (collected, reason) => {
            if (reason == 'MAX') {
                const data = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name.toLowerCase() == 'app-logs' && ch.type == 'text');
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`New Application`)
                    .setDescription(`**from** <@${message.author.id}>`)
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                const e = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`Questions and Answers:`)
                    .setDescription(`${res.map(d => `**${d.question} - Answer:** ${d.answer}`).join("\n")}`, '\n ^^^^')
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                dmChannel.channel.send('Your application has been recorded thanks!')
                // trying to code this
                if (!data) {
                    message.guild.channels.create('app-logs', {
                        type: 'text',
                        permissionOverwrites: [{
                                id: message.guild.id,
                                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },
                            {
                                id: message.author.id,
                                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },
                            {
                                id: client.user.id,
                                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },
                        ],

                    })

                    await data.send(embed)
                    await data.send(e)
                }
                await data.send(embed)
                await data.send(e)
                console.log(`${res.map(d => `${d.question} - ${d.answer}`).join("\n")}`)
                console.log(`this is an application by from @${message.author.tag} in the guild (${message.guild.name})`)


            }
        })
    }
}
```

And the error is:

> 0|index  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

I am trying to understand where this error is coming from and why?

Answer (score 0):

You have this block of code:

```
if (!data) {
                    message.guild.channels.create('app-logs', {
                        type: 'text',
                        permissionOverwrites: [{
                                id: message.guild.id,
                                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },
                            {
                                id: message.author.id,
                                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },
                            {
                                id: client.user.id,
                                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                            },
                        ],

                    })

                    await data.send(embed)
                    await data.send(e)
                }
```

Which tests that data is falsy, creates a channel, and then acts on data without setting it to anything. I suspect you want to await the result of channels.create and save the result in data:

```
   data = await  message.guild.channels.create('app-logs', { // ...
      //...
   );


   if (data) {
      await data.send(embed)
      await data.send(e)
   }
```

You probably want to have an exception handler around this in case send fails for other reasons (like latency, etc)